# Disabling .click() and then re-enabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to make it so that once an element get's clicked, the click function won't work until my `$.post` is complete.

```
<div id="textbox_item">Click me</div>
```

This is what I have now but it's not working. I am assuming `.prop('disabled', true)` does not work for `div` elements. Could anyone help me out?

```
$("#textbox_item").click(function() {

    //don't let anyone click .textbox_item until $.post is complete
    $("#textbox_item").prop('disabled', true).text("Doing something..");

    $.post("/action", { item: "123" }).done(function( data ) { 
        $("#textbox_item").prop('disabled', false).text("Click me");        
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting and checking `.data()` for a "disabled" data attribute.

```
$(".textbox_item").click(function() {
    //don't do anything if #textbox_item has been disabled
    if($("#textbox_item").data('disabled')) { return false; }

    //don't let anyone click .textbox_item until $.post is complete
    $("#textbox_item").data('disabled', true).text("Doing something..");

    $.post("/action", { item: "123" }).done(function( data ) { 
        $("#textbox_item").data('disabled', false).text("Click me");
    });

});
```

I also noticed that you seem to be mixing ID and class selectors - I don't know if this is intentional or not, but I advise double-checking to make sure you know what you're disabling and clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems here:

- You try to use a button property on a div which won't work. HTML `Disable` property does not apply to divs.
- You are mixing selectors. Your `Click me` div has a class `textbox_item` but your call `$("#textbox_item")` is looking for something with `textbox_item` as id not as a class. You should use `$(".textbox_item")` everytime you want to refer to this element.

**HTML**

`<button class="textbox_item">Click me</button>`

**JS**

```
$(".textbox_item").click(function()
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $.post("/action", { item: "123" }).done(function( data ) { 
       $(".textbox_item").prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the provided function by the jquery library specifically for this?

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
button.one('click', function() {
     //on ajax success
     Button.one('click', func)
})
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed, but I want to be able to click the button more than once. Just not until the process is finished.

Comment: which is why you re-attach the event after you're done processing